# How to get ending date when starting date and no of dates are given in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to get ending date when starting date and no dates are give.
EX: start date in 2000-09-29 and what is the date after 10 days.

I there any java api to get it easily???

Comment: Sure, read the documentation of `java.time` (in Java 8) or Joda-Time (if you have Java 7 or lower).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have your date object then you can use Calendar instance like:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date); 
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);
```

then call it like:

```
c.getTime()
```

If you're using Java 8

```
LocalDateTime.from(date.toInstant()).plusDays(10);
```